# What's the meaning of “the initial non-assignment word on the line” in shell

Tags: bash, bash-completion

In [Programmable Completion Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) complete command, there is a -I argument.
It said:

> The -I option indicates that other supplied options and actions should apply to completion on **the initial non-assignment word on the line**, or **after a command delimiter** such as ‘;’ or ‘|’, which is usually command name completion.

I don't understand "the initial non-assignment word on the line" , can someone give an example.

I set a complete by `complete -W 'AA BB' -I`, It worked "after a command delimiter"

```
root@aliecs:~# complete -W 'AA BB' -I
root@aliecs:~# ls &&<tab><tab>
AA  BB  
root@aliecs:~# ls ;<tab><tab>
AA  BB  
root@aliecs:~# ls |<tab><tab>
AA  BB  
root@aliecs:~# ls ||<tab><tab>
AA  BB
```

I want an example of "the initial non-assignment word on the line"

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); post the text itself (in [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361), so it displays accurately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell commands consist of a series of words (where "word" has a formal meaning). An assignment word is one that contains a `=`:

```
foo=5
```

That's a single word, though in other languages you might consider that the word `foo`, an `=`, and a `5`, just not separated by whitespace.

Commands can *begin* with 0 or more assignment words. An assignment word is not treated as the name of the command to execute, but as a variable assignment that is "local" to that command. For example,

```
x=5 foo
```

is a command that runs a program named `foo` with a variable `x` in its environment with the value `5`, *not* a command named `x=5` with an argument `foo`.

For completion purposes, you don't really want to do completion on assignments, because the whole point of the assignment is to define something that might not already exist, and how would the shell know how to complete something you haven't defined yet? So the `complete` command ignores the assignment words at the beginning of a command line, and focuses on the first word that could be the name of the command to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Example：

```
root@aliecs:~# complete -W 'AA BB BC' -I
root@aliecs:~# foo=1 B<tab><tab>
BB  BC  
root@aliecs:~# B<tab><tab>
BB  BC
```

The “B” is “non-assignment”.
Thanks @chepner’s answer.